# Angular Google Maps waypoints don't display with dynamic waypoint array

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps

I'm trying to get waypoints in between my origin and destination address in Angular Google Maps.
I have an array 
`waypoints: any`

and a method to add waypoints dynamically: 
`addWaypoint($event) {
        this.waypoints.push({
            location: { lat: $event.geoLocation.latitude, lng: $event.geoLocation.longitude},
            stopover: true
        });
        console.log(this.waypoints);
    }`

but those waypoints won't display on the map.

```
 <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom">
                <agm-marker *ngIf="!destination" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
                <agm-direction *ngIf="destination" [origin]="origin" [destination]="destination" [waypoints]="waypoints">
                </agm-direction>
 </agm-map>
```

If I add waypoints static to the array, they will be shown:

```
addWaypoint($event) {
    this.waypoints = [{
        location: { lat: $event.geoLocation.latitude, lng: $event.geoLocation.longitude},
        stopover: true
    }];
    console.log(this.waypoints);
}
```

The console output is in both cases the same:

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this by using the spread operator:

```
this.waypoints = [...this.waypoints, ...[{
        location: { lat: $event.geoLocation.latitude, lng: $event.geoLocation.longitude},
        stopover: true
    }]];
```